# Changing a row value in one table to match a row value in another table when joining

Tags: mysql

I'm working with a database that is not normalized efficiently so I am having to get creative in joining tables. I have one table that has a column name 'direction_or' with full names like 'Northwest','Southwest' and another table with the same column name but abbreviates them like 'NW','SW' and I am needing to join the tables on those parameters. Joining on keys is not possible unfortunately.

I was wondering if it is possible to use a CASE WHEN or something to evaluate the full name and then make it the abbreviated name then JOINING the tables based on that abbreviated name in one query.

Like I said I'm having to get creative and this has got me stumped.

Something like this, forgive me for my ignorance.

`SELECT * FROM user.directions AS A (somehow change the value of A.direction_or AS newAbb) LEFT JOIN stored.directons AS B ON A.newAbb = B.direction_or`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have the right to alter the database ? For instance, create table ?

Comment: Yeah I am able to create tables.

Comment: Then I think the best way would be to use enums, see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an easy yet heavy way, you can :

create a table pairing terms. It should be pretty lightweight and most probably cached everytime you use it, but it still have a weight since imbriqued select.

You would then do : 
    SELECT * FROM user.directions AS A LEFT JOIN stored.directons AS B ON (select desiredvalue from StatesAndAbreviation where state = A.newAbb) = B.direction_or

or something like this.

And other way to work around this would be to use enums. By creating two enums and mapping corresponding strings to equivalent integers, you could probably compare them quite easily. You need to alter the tables to change the types of the varchar -> corresponding enum.

See: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html

Edit:  When comparing enums, you would probably have to do something awkward like `where A.enumvar+0 = B.enumvar+0`. You can still try without it though since the code would be easier to read if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will play around with these. Great ideas.

Comment: And if it ends up working, don't hesitate to select the answer that worked for you, it will helps the answerer as well as prevent the question to polute StackOverflow.

Comment: Used the table method as a quick fix, works perfect.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lookup table which maps full names to abbreviated names, then join with that table in your query.

Else you can also do it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        CASE
            WHEN direction_or = 'Northwest' THEN 'NW'
            WHEN direction_or = 'Southwest' THEN 'SW'
            -- all other possibilities here
            ELSE ''
        END as direction_or_abb

    FROM user.directions
) a

JOIN stored.directions b
    ON a.direction_or_abb = b.direction_or
```

Comment: Thanks for that response, Alceste_'s table idea,  which was your first suggestion worked well. I will mess around with your query method too, I have about 7 other tables i'm joining on top of the two in the example.